# Logic state explanation

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic

[image]

If the start push button is pressed, is the logic level at RA5 1 or 0?

Comment: Consider RA5 has a huge resistor internally of Mega ohms order. And switch has zero resistance.

Answer (score 1):

When the button pressed, RA5 changes from VCC to GND, aka from HIGH to LOW.

Now you get to choose which logic convention you are using. You could use positive logic, which means it's '0' or False at GND potential, or negative logic, which means it's a '1' or True when LOW.

There are some times, and some logic families, for which the use of negative logic is more 'logical', or gives better speed or noise immunity performance, than the more intuitive positive logic.

Most of the time, especially for beginners, I'd recommend positive logic, as there are fewer inversions to think through. However note that a positive action, pressing the button, results in the signal going 'False' when using a positive logic convention. So maybe choosing negative logic when pullups are involved is easier. You choose which works better for you.

Comment: If the resistors weren't there, what would the logic level be?

Comment: With no resistors (leave them open circuit) the logic level would be undefined (BAD!) with the switch open, then LOW with the switch closed. With no resistors (replace them with wire) the logic level would be HIGH with the switch open, and the power supply would be shorted  (BAD!) with the switch closed.

Answer (score 1):

It will be LOW (0) when START button are pressed because it connects RA5 to the ground directly thus it's voltage will be at ground (0V).

Those resistors above are so-called "pull-up" resistors. They connected to Vcc thus providing HIGH (1) level through them when there is no other current path, i.e. the START button are unpressed (open). Once you press START, current start to flows through it to the ground leaving pin RA5 at LOW (0).

In inverted logic, HIGH level means logical 0, LOW level means logical 1. But considering those pin names comes from some sort of PIC MCU by their names, these use direct logic where HIGH=1, LOW=0.

Comment: So current flows in the path with less resistance? What if there were no resistors, what would the logic level be then?

Comment: Current flows from positive to negative terminal and mostly described by Ohm's law. If there were no resistors - this is called a short circuit and results a failure as it virtually allows infinite current to flow (in reality there is always some resistance, so current will be very high instead).

Comment: Current flows proportionally to resistance (Ohm's law). MCU PIN configured as input have a very high impendence. Very low leakage current flows through it. So as long as START are open it has HIGH level. Once start are connected almost all current after resistors flows to ground, the very littly leakage which flows to the PIN are so small what it's not affecting it's logical state. MCU INPUT pin are usually implemented as Schmitt trigger, so they have some sort of hysteresis for states too btw.

Comment: Please don't add information in comments - edit it into your question's text flow (not at the end under 'EDIT'). Otherwise, people have to piece together your actual answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM this wasn't information added to the answer. It's the answers to follow-up questions in comments from OP.